# CUSTOM check if input type button checked PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a little problem with one of my script:

```
    <label><input type="radio" name="tshirt-size" value="giraffe" checked="checked" ><img src="./images/giraffe.png"></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="tshirt-size" value="bear"><img src="./images/bear.png"></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="tshirt-size" value="monkey"><img src="./images/monkey.png"></label>
```

and the selected code:

```
      <?php
            $sql="SELECT distinct size FROM total where left_quantity > 0 order by ID"; 
            echo "<select name='size'>"; 
            echo "<option disabled>SELECT SIZE</option>"; 
            foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){
                echo "<option value = $row[size]> $row[size]</option>"; 
            }
            echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

table database:

`CREATE TABLE stocuri_tricouri (
  id int(100) NOT NULL,
  type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  size varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  left_quantity int(100) NOT NULL,
  stoc_ramas int(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

```
INSERT INTO `stocuri_tricouri` (`id`, `type`, `size`, `initial_quantity`, `left_quantity`) VALUES (1, 'giraffe', 'S', 250, 250), (2, 'giraffe', 'M', 250, 250), (3, 'giraffe', 'L', 250, 250), (4, 'bear', 'S', 250, 250), (5, 'bear', 'M', 150, 0), (6, 'bear', 'L', 250, 250), (7, 'monkey', 'S', 250, 250), (8, 'monkey', 'M', 250, 250), (9, 'monkey', 'L', 250, 250);
```

I want to select the size for each radio button, not for all, if i delete the `distinct` the select will be with all data... and i want date from each input.

with `distinct`: size are: S, M, L

without `distinct`: S,M,L,S,M,L,S,M,L

[with distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMWf1.png)

[without distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjBI7.png)

Comment: *"I want to select the size **for each** radio button, **not for all**"* - That's a bit confusing, since radios of the same name can only allow "one choice". If you want multiples, then you'll need to use checkboxes and treat them as an array. You also appear to be missing code for this, such as POST arrays and the form's method is unknown.

Comment: You've an answer below; see that. If it solved it, consider accepting the answer. If it did not, place a comment under it.

Comment: i have a select under the radio buttons and now all the data are there S,M,L ..S,M,L and after i select the radio button it should be on select only: S,M,L not whole database, i attached 2 pictured with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code, customize it as per your requirements.

```
    for ($i=0;$i <count($result);$i++) {
        $htmltext = $result[$i]['firstname'].' '.$result[$i]['lastname'];
        $id = $result[$i]['id'];
        $IsSelected = ($id==$selected ? 'selected' : '');
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$id?>" <?=$IsSelected?>><?=$htmltext?></option>
        <?php
    }
```

What I've done here is added condition for selected option value if it match then print `selected` as attribute of option. `$selected` is ID which you need to select, it could be anything.

Comment: can't use it, it's a bit hard to customize it.

Comment: Try that and let me know if it won't work, I would be glad to help you anytime !!